# How to create an Excel Pie Chart using Infragistics and c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, excel-2010, infragistics

I'm developing a web site using c# and MVC4. In one of the sections I have a couple of pie charts that are created using highcharts lib and are based on a table of totals next to the charts.

I need to export to excel both the table with the totals and the charts, and I need to do it in a way in which, once exported, if the table changes in excel the graph will also be updated inside the spreadsheet.

My company is using Infragistics to export to excel, so exporting the table is not a problem, but I'm not sure how to export the pie charts.

I saw [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e7dba804-f136-485f-822c-48c6709bec57/how-to-create-pie-chart-in-excel2003-using-c?forum=vsto) example where a pivot table is created and feed to the table, but I noticed that it is using native excel libraries instead of Infragistics, I've been trying to migrate this but can't seem to find the equivalent to Excel.Application inside Infragistics lib.

Another solution that occur to me is that maybe I can enter a formula inside a cell and have it create the pie chart but I don't think this is possible since, if I'm not wrong, the pie chart is not even included in a cell, but it is a graphic that floats inside the spreadsheet.

So if anyone has had any experience drawing a pie chart from c# to excel using Infragistics and can point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a developer at Infragistics and work on the Excel library. Currently, charts will be round-tripped when a file is loaded and saved, but they cannot be manipulated or created at run-time in our object model. You can submit a feature request for this ability here: http://ideas.infragistics.com/

Comment: Hey Mike thanks for the answer, the way I'm working around this is, I decided to add a template to my project which will already contain the charts and only update the cells to which the charts are referencing, the problem is, the formula for each chart is like =Sheet1!$D$9:$D$13,Sheet1!$G$9:$G$13, but I need to change the sheet name from my app when printing the report, by doing so the charts break, I'm doing workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault().Name = "some name"; but it is not working, do you know if there is a method to update the sheet name that will also update all of the name references

Comment: @Vic Setting the Name property of a Worksheet should find all 3D references and update them to use the new name. If that isn't working for charts, it might be a bug. You should probably submit this to developer support so it can be logged and investigated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Infragistics, I don't know if you can create an Excel pie chart, but if you want to create it in a web or windows application, use this:

[Infragistics® Chart](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76620448-1377-4440-9969-8a7da3af76e0)